# kubernetes kubedns - sidecar and masq crashes if I do a nslookup

Tags: dns

I am facing a strange issue
Here are my kubernetes details

```
Kubernetes version:  1.6.4
OS: Ubuntu 17.04
```

I use the YAML files from the following link to install kube-dns
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns/

Step 1

I then try to launch busybox using

```
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox – sh
```

Now when I do nslookup kubernetes it works.
Now when I try to see the docker logs for my sidecar I see the following

```
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0721 17:15:25.067730       1 main.go:48] Version v1.14.3-4-gee838f6
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0721 17:15:25.067981       1 server.go:45] Starting server (options {DnsMasqPort:53 DnsMasqAddr:127.0.0.1 DnsMasqPollIntervalMs:5000 Probes:[{Label:kubedns Server:127.0.0.1:10053 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1} {Label:dnsmasq Server:127.0.0.1:53 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}] PrometheusAddr:0.0.0.0 PrometheusPort:10054 PrometheusPath:/metrics PrometheusNamespace:kubedns})
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0721 17:15:25.068191       1 dnsprobe.go:75] Starting dnsProbe {Label:kubedns Server:127.0.0.1:10053 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0721 17:15:25.068398       1 dnsprobe.go:75] Starting dnsProbe {Label:dnsmasq Server:127.0.0.1:53 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse:
```

Step 2
If I do a nslookup against a name (say nslookup ABCD) that I know does not exist in kubedns (as a A record) then I see following logs in my dnsmesg container

```
I0718 17:26:33.738368       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[13]: Maximum number of concurrent DNS queries reached (max: 150)
```

And at the same time I see following in sidecar

```
dns sidecar errorERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0720 02:09:37.975054       1 main.go:48] Version v1.14.3-4-gee838f6
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0720 02:09:37.975140       1 server.go:45] Starting server (options {DnsMasqPort:53 DnsMasqAddr:127.0.0.1 DnsMasqPollIntervalMs:5000 Probes:[{Label:kubedns Server:127.0.0.1:10053 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1} {Label:dnsmasq Server:127.0.0.1:53 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}] PrometheusAddr:0.0.0.0 PrometheusPort:10054 PrometheusPath:/metrics PrometheusNamespace:kubedns})
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0720 02:09:37.975160       1 dnsprobe.go:75] Starting dnsProbe {Label:kubedns Server:127.0.0.1:10053 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0720 02:09:37.975200       1 dnsprobe.go:75] Starting dnsProbe {Label:dnsmasq Server:127.0.0.1:53 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: W0720 02:12:50.090595       1 server.go:64] Error getting metrics from dnsmasq: read udp 127.0.0.1:36473->127.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: W0720 02:13:03.607740       1 server.go:64] Error getting metrics from dnsmasq: read udp 127.0.0.1:56334->127.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: W0720 02:13:10.609651       1 server.go:64] Error getting metrics from dnsmasq: read udp 127.0.0.1:39976->127.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: W0720 02:13:23.644035       1 server.go:64] Error getting metrics from dnsmasq: read udp 127.0.0.1:57226->127.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout
```

Step 3
Now here is a bummer after 5minutes or 10 minutes my sidecar and dnsmasq both crash and new containers get recreated.

A few other details about my K8s cluster 
I am using VMWare workstation 12 Pro to run my cluster on one node and I have enabled RBAC and am using client certificates for authentication

SOS. Can someone point me in the right direction? Have spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Folks refer to this github link where I discussed this and the issue was resolved. 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49411

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04, where on top of `/etc/resolve.conf` and `systemd-resolved` a third system with [netplan](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/) comes into play. But that doesn´t bother `kube-dns` - as already described on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49411#issuecomment-318118824), `kube-dns` simply picks the contents of `/etc/resolve.conf` which was in my case:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

It turned out, that this is simply **a known Ubuntu systemd-resolved bug** (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/974482/451114) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952284/dns-system-is-failing-to-resolve-domain-names-occasionally#comment1589832_952284) so answers). Long story short, there´s only one workaround (really, I also didn´t believe it and tried to use [systemd-resolved configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/973025/451114) editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restarting the service - but that didn´t work for me). Just (re)move the original `/etc/resolv.conf` and replace it with a link to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf_orig
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Now your `/etc/resolve.conf` should have the correct nameserver, which is `nameserver 10.0.2.3` in my case, where I´am using VirtualBox (that may differ for your setup!). Now after `kube-dns` was re-applied, it picks up the correct nameserver for every nslookup and everything works fine:

```
kubectl exec -it busybox-68654f944b-7rdzs -- nslookup kubernetes
```

If you´re interested, here´s an implementation with Ansible for that problem: https://github.com/jonashackt/kubernetes-the-ansible-way/issues/6

---

**Update 08/29/2018:** The current `busybox` image has DNS lookup problems (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66924). Try to run version `1.28.4` explicitely with:

```
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox:1.28.4 --command -- sleep 3600
```

This should prevent you from days of searching!

Comment: I applied the same solution on my cluster and DNS is working now. Did you uninstall systemd-resolve after changes?

Comment: No, I didn't uninstall systemd-resolve afterwards - I think, Ubuntu relies on that subsystem in it's newer versions - so that might not be a good idea.

Comment: sure ! but, even after creating a symbolic link as above. resolv.conf points to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf and nslookup command shows random behaviour. works sometimes, and does not works sometimes. anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 which AFAIK does not run systemd-resolved

Which explains why I could not find /run/systemd/resolve(resolv.conf) folder to symlink my /etc/resolv.conf to

Apparently systemd-resolved was introduced in version 16.10

I did switch to using version 1.28.4 of busybox but that didn't help any either.